# linkTo and action helpers default events

Tags: ember.js

Is there a way to replace the default event that triggers the linkTo and action helpers?

I want to respond to mousedown rather than click...

It is to make the interface work a little faster.

thanks

Comment: As far as I know, this would require a re-write or at least edits in [`LinkView`](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.0.0-rc.2/packages/ember-routing/lib/helpers/link_to.js) since it's not part of the public API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Action helper:**

The answer can be found in official guide:
Specify the type of event: http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/

```
<p>
  <button {{action "select" post on="mouseUp"}}>✓</button>
  {{post.title}}
</p>
```

List of available event: http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/the-view-layer/#toc_adding-new-events

---

**LinkTo helper:**

As `{{linkTo}}` doesn't have an `on` option like `{{action}}`, this helper can simulate the same result by define the `eventManager` property.

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('linkAction', function (name) {
    var options = [].slice.call(arguments, -1)[0];
    var params = [].slice.call(arguments, 1, -1);

    var hash = options.hash;

    hash.namedRoute = name;
    hash.currentWhen = hash.currentWhen || name;

    hash.parameters = {
        context: this,
        options: options,
        params: params
    };

    var LinkView = Ember.LinkView.extend({
        didInsertElement: function () {
            this.eventManager = Ember.Object.create({});
            this.eventManager.click = function () {
                return false;
            };
            this.eventManager[hash.on] = function (e, v) {
                Ember.LinkView.prototype.click.call(v, e);
            }
        }
    })

    return Ember.Handlebars.helpers.view.call(this, LinkView, options);
});
```

How to use:

```
{{#linkAction route on="mouseEnter"}}Text{{/linkAction}}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/indream/mKVU8/1/

Reference: [Action helper](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.0.0-rc.3/packages/ember-routing/lib/helpers/action.js) [LinkTo helper](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.0.0-rc.3/packages/ember-routing/lib/helpers/link_to.js)

Comment: Lovely,  this is good for action, but is there an equivalent for linkTo? cheers

Comment: I wrote a new helper that is the same as linkTo but uses the mouseDown event to trigger. Cheers for the advice!

Comment: @l33z3r I've updated the answer with a modified linkTo helper. Please have a try.

Comment: Is there a way to replace the default event that the handlebars action uses? I would like to make it default to something other than click, without having to specify on="mouseDown" in my templates.

Comment: You need to modify the source code of action helper. You can hard code it or use `hash.on || App.actionDefault || "click"` to specify it dynamically. [Action helper](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-routing/lib/helpers/action.js#L289)